What type of directions are fruitful to innovate in quantum hardware?
Question about ancilla qubits How are ancilla qubits physically prepared and measured? inspired this one.
Does it make sense to produce such quantum hardware, where ancilla qubits are different to other qubits for some properties like coherence time, or quality of qubits?
Then does it make sense for example to combine two different form of quantum computers and merge them as one? What type of algorithms could potentially benefit from such idea?

I think you are asking two different questions under a somewhat broad title. Please try to be more specific and avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Keep in mind that making qubits interact is already difficult within a quantum chip, let alone across quantum computers with different physical hardwares and paradigms. Tuning some trade-off between coherence time and quality of some dedicated qubits within a chip might be already done.

This recent review paper may be the sort of thing you're looking for. I'll provide a brief overview of the general idea and explain why this hybrid approach could offer a powerful alternative to the strict discrete variable (DV) or continuous variable (CV) approaches. I recommend exploring the review in more detail for specifics that may interest you.
Hybrid Quantum Processors: Combining Qubits and Oscillators
In the context of hybrid quantum processors, the system typically consists of a qubit coupled to an oscillator, such as a transmon qubit coupled to a microwave cavity. In this setup, the oscillator serves as the memory qubit, while the transmon functions as an auxiliary qubit. In the case of microwave cavities coupled to transmons, the lifetime of the cavity is greater than that of the transmon (which can be a limiting factor when using the transmon to stabilize a qubit encoded in the cavity).
Advantages of Hybrid Approaches
1. Infinite Hilbert Space and Simple Error Model: One major advantage of this approach is that the oscillator provides a countably infinite Hilbert space with a relatively simple error model. In microwave cavities, the error model is highly biased, with the dominant error being photon loss. This hardware efficiency has led to realizations of error correction beyond the break-even, as demonstrated here for a GKP code, here for a Schrodinger-cat code, and here for a binomial code. For the GKP code, a GKP qubit was encoded in the cavity, with an auxiliary transmon qubit facilitating error correction via the sBs protocol (see Section V.B in this GKP review). The potential of combining oscillator qubits with discrete variable codes (e.g., using GKP data qubits stabilized by two-level qubits to form a surface code) is also promising. For instance, this paper demonstrated that a GKP-surface code could achieve a logical error rate of $< 10^{-7}$ using 291 modes and 97 two-level qubits, compared to 1457 bare qubits. It's worth noting that in the context of GKP codes, the use of biased-noise qubits (e.g., Kerr-Cat qubits) to improve logical error rates, compared to transmons, remains relatively unexplored but could also provide some improvement. For example, in the experimental realisation of a GKP code, the authors found that the GKP qubit is more sensitive to auxillary qubit bit flips than auxillary qubit phase flips.
2. Programmable Quantum Simulators: Another advantage of hardware with native bosonic modes is their applicability in constructing programmable quantum simulators for physical models that involve bosons, such as the bosonic Hubbard model in condensed matter physics or lattice gauge theories in particle physics. This is a possible advantage as it's known that there are  significant difficulties
in efficiently representing bosons using qubits.
Since answering this question, a companion paper to the previously mentioned review paper has been published. This companion paper provides, in much greater detail, the potential advantages of this hybrid architecture. They also demonstrates concrete asymptotic scaling improvements over all-qubit hardware (in the context of simulating lattice gauge theories).
Conclusion
This brief overview provides some motivation for exploring hybrid quantum processors. The review paper offers a more in-depth discussion, with concepts applicable to other hardware platforms, such as hybrid CV-DV trapped ion and neutral atom systems.
